# Sobol values greater than 1 after Owen scrambling

Tags: r, random, montecarlo

The `sobol()` function in the `randtoolbox` (version 1.17) package in `R` (version 3.3.2) sometimes gives values greater than 1 (see example below). Is this a bug or does Owen scrambling generate values significantly outside the range of underlying sequence? I looked at the following reference and didn't find a mention of this issue.

I. Lirkov, S. Margenov, and J. Wasniewski (Eds.): LSSC 2009, LNCS 5910, pp. 459–466, 2010.

MWE:

```
library('randtoolbox')

sobolSeq = sobol(n=100000,dim=10,seed=84,scrambling=1)
print(max(sobolSeq ))
```

Output:

```
Warning message:
In sobol(n = 1e+05, dim = 10, seed = 84, scrambling = 1) :
  A call to sobol() raised an error by generating numerics greater or equal than 1.

[1] 1.999992
```

Comment: It certainly sounds like a bug, as suggested by "raised an error"

Comment: Looks like a bug related to scrambling (should be mod, i think?)

Comment: It is curious. Other seeds (I've tried about 10) don't seem to generate the error, even with  larger `n`.

Comment: Of the seed values in the range 1 to 100, the values 24, 52, and 84 raise the error and the other 97 values don't.